# What is a good configuration for a zpool built from 8-10 SSD for a home file server exported via NFS?

Tags: nfs, solaris, zfs, home-directory

So we have a bunch of SSD disks and would like to put them in a zpool on a Solaris 10 system. The file system will be exported via NFS to about 50 Ubuntu clients which will mount it as their $HOME. I expect that the bandwidth will not exceed 1 Gbit/s, but the latency should be as low as possible because of the Desktop environments running on the clients.

1. **What is a good configuration for such a zpool?** Currently we have one `raidz2` with 8 disks + 2 hot spares, but I've read that since a single `raidz` is just a single vdev, the performance is limited to the speed of a single disk.
2. **What are the critical NFS server/client parameters that can be tuned?** Currently we use NFS3 with `noatime` and default `rsize/wsize`, but perhaps there is a better choice for the clients running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use *Solaris*?

Ubuntu can run ZFS. Other Linux variants can support ZFS. There are other Solaris-derived operating systems that can do it (OmniOS, OpenIndiana, etc.). Oh, and FreeBSD... Not to mention the appliance solutions: Zetavault, QuantaStor, napp-it, Nexenta, Cloudbyte...

Anyway, I would use ZFS mirrors. Multiple vdevs and gives you an option to expand. I'm not a fan of RAIDZ1/2/3 unless capacity is a concern. But since you have *"a bunch"* of disks, maybe that's not an issue. What type of disks are they?

As far as NFS settings, that's going to depend on the OS you choose. Also think about your NFS export settings (sync versus async) and possibly increase the number of NFS server threads.

Comment: Samsung SSD 840 5B0Q. We have Solaris on other file servers so I'd like to keep it unless there's a good reason to switch. But don't mirrors offer a smaller fault tolerance? As for NFS we have `NFSD_SERVERS=2048`, `LOCKD_SERVERS=1024` and `*_LISTEN_BACKLOG=32` on the server side, but the number of nfsd threads is usually around 300-400.

Comment: May I ask why anti-solaris? My support contract with them is expiring soon so I'm open to other options. I created the ZPOOLs with the older exportable version of ZFS. Is enterprise support available for ZoL? Omni and Nexenta support seem poorly priced when compared to Solaris.  I've had pretty decent experiences with Oracle support with my ~250 TB across 4 front-end servers.

Comment: If you're a Solaris shop, use it. Most people doing ZFS and asking for help with ZFS are coming from other platforms.

Comment: Ok cool. I wouldn't say we're a Solaris shop per-say.  Am definitely open to alternatives but was disappointed that Omni was double the price.